# Why is ToArray() used when using string.Join with a List<string>?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to combine `List<string> strings` using `string.Join(",", strings)` but everything I'm reading says I should do:

`string.Join(",", strings.ToArray())`

Is there a certain reason I have to/should use `.ToArray()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`string.Join` only started accepting `IEnumerable<string>` (and indeed a generic overload) as of .NET 4. Presumably you're looking at code (or instructions) written with .NET 3.5 or earlier in mind. Compare the overloads:

- [`string.Join` in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [`string.Join` in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Probably because everything you're reading was written for an earlier version of the framework.  The `string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` method was added in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a certain reason I have to/should use .ToArray()?

You don't have to; instead, you're likely looking at older code which existed before the current overloads that don't require you to call `ToArray`. The new overloads that accept `IEnumerable<string>` didn't come until .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use .ToArray() in .Net v4 and above.  In v4 IEnumerable plays a big part and a lot of extensions got added.

So, if need to compile with v3.5 or below you will need to use .ToArray(), but with 4.0 and above your code is correct.