# Efficient way to join strings with a separator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, performance

```
foreach (SessionTeacher sessionTeacher in sessionTeachers)
{
   Person person = EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(sessionTeacher.PersonID);
   ltrlSpeakers.Text += person.Name1 + ", ";
}
```

here `ltrlSpeakers.Text` will have something like this "abc, def, " that is extra comma and space at the end which I have to remove.

```
// removing extra comma and space

ltrlSpeakers.Text = ltrlSpeakers.Text.ToString().Remove(ltrlSpeakers.Text.ToString().Length - 2, 2);
```

it's working fine but is there a better more efficient simple way?

Comment: Is this really one of the least efficient parts of your application? I would be more concerned with the fact that you are using [magic numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/299327).

Comment: @RyanGates which ones ?

Comment: `ltrlSpeakers.Text.ToString().Length - 2, 2` the `2`'s

Comment: thats what i wanna remove , and string.join got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var personNames = sessionTeachers.Select(
      st => EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(st.PersonID).Name1);
ltrlSpeakers.Text = string.Join(", ", personNames);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Using LINQ:

```
string result = string.Join(",",
(from t in sessionTeachers select EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(t.PersonID).Name1))
```

Comment: I believe the call to ToArray() is not required.

Comment: Call to `ToArray` is required for all .NET versions before 4, so this call might be necessary d(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092815/why-is-toarray-used-when-using-string-join-with-a-liststring).

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method instead.

```
ltrlSpeakers.Text = string.Join(
    ", ", 
    sessionTeachers.Select(z => z.EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(z.PersonID).Name1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
        ltrlSpeakers.Text = 
        String.Join(", ",
            sessionTeachers
                .Select(teacher => EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(teacher.PersonID).Name1)
                .ToArray()
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

best way is

```
ltrlSpeakers.Text = 
        String.Join(", ",
            sessionTeachers
                .Select(teacher => EMS.PWDAL.DALHelper.GetPersonByID(teacher.PersonID).Name1)
                .ToArray()
        );
ltrlSpeakers.Text = ltrlSpeakers.Text.trimend(',')
```